# How to set the dynamic ids for link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a horizontal menu. I want to create an id for each using jQuery. My code is:

```
<div class="menuBar">
    <div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top">
        <span><a href="#" onclick="Home()">Home</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top">
        <span><a href="#" onclick="NewTransaction()" id="menu2">New Transaction</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here menu has no id. I want to create id dynamically using jQuery. How can I do this? I did an example like this, but it is not working:

```
var i = 0;
$('.menuHeader').each(function () {
    i++;
    newID = menu + i;
    $(this).attr('id', newID);
    $(this).val(i);
});
```

Comment: Do you find code like this easier to read? I prefer it to be left aligned... ;) Please explain what "it is not working" means. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Juhana posted a link to your previous question, which is exactly the same. You commented on one of the answers: *"But its not working."*. This does not help anyone! "It does not work" is the **worst** problem description because it does not contain *any* information which can be used to solve the problem. If you want to get helpful answers, you have to be more specific about **what** exactly "does not work".

Comment: I believe you don't need to add new ID for each div. You can use `$('.menuHeader:eq(' + number + ')' ).anyfunction()` which is easier (at least for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, no need of extra variable `i`:

```
$('.menuHeader').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', 'menu' + ($(this).index() + 1));
    $(this).val($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

Comment: do it here pls jsfiddle.net/cE4GM

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/cE4GM/4/

Comment: its ok.But How can I set it in my html

Comment: It has been set. Just inspect the `div` html once.

Comment: I need like this <span><a href="#" onclick="Home()" id="dynamically generated value">Home</a></span>

Comment: One min, your question is "How to generate ids for div", which has been set, but here you are saying you want to set the dynamic ids for links. Please confirm your requirement.

Comment: want to set the dynamic ids for links

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/cE4GM/11/

Answer (score 6):

The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0.

You have also omitted the quotes when you concatenated *menu* string with `i` variable.

```
$('.menuHeader').each(function (i) {
  $(this).find('a').attr('id', 'menu' + (i + 1));
  $(this).html((i + 1) + '. ' + $(this).html());
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cE4GM/10/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cE4GM/  really great work sir

Comment: @Matei Mihai- Your jsfiddle demo not working properly..

Comment: What do you mean? what is not working?

Comment: I cannot set the id to my html

Comment: I've just edited my answer and the jsfiddle link

Comment: its ok yar, But I need like this <span><a href="#" onclick="Home()" id="dynamically generated value">Home</a></span>

Comment: You updated this jsfiddle????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cE4GM/10/

Comment: want to set the dynamic ids for links

Comment: @Agent1: That's what the code is doing...

Comment: @FelixKling-yes its worked

Comment: I don't understood why you accepted another answer.. even if that answer is not correctly written..

Comment: @MateiMihai-It is also worked.Here I can set the id of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $('.menuHeader').each(function (i) {
      newID = "menu_" + i;
      $(this).attr('id', newID);
      $(this).val(i);
    });
```

Comment: It will generate only at the run time.